# Derivation of beta-beat in S.Y. Lee's Accelerator Physics

Tags: accelerator-physics

I'm following S.Y. Lee's Accelerator Physics (Fourth Edition), specifically Chapter 2 Transverse Motion, III.4 Quadrupole Field (Gradient) Errors. In paragraph (B) the beta-beat is derived in the following way (p. 96):

> [...] The one-turn transfer matrix at $s_2$ and the change of the off-diagonal matrix element are
> $$ M(s_2) = M(s_2+C|s_1)m(s_1)M(s_1|s_2) $$
> $$ \Delta\left[M(s_2)\right]_{12} = -k_1ds_1\beta_1\beta_2\sin(\nu_0(\phi_1 - \phi_2))\sin(\nu_0(2\pi + \phi_2 - \phi_1))$$
> where $\beta_1 = \beta(s_1)$, $\beta_2 = \beta(s_2)$, $\phi_1 = \psi(s_1)/\nu_0$ and $\phi_2 = \psi(s_2)/\nu_0$ are the values of the unperturbed betatron functions. Since $M_{12} = \tilde{\beta}_2\sin\Phi$, where $\tilde{\beta}_2 = \tilde{\beta}(s_2)$ and $\Phi$ are the perturbed betatron function and betatron phase advance, we find
> $$ (\Delta\beta_2)\sin\Phi_0 = \Delta M_{12} - \beta_2\cos\Phi_0\Delta\Phi = -\frac{1}{2}k_1ds_1\beta_1\beta_2\cos(2\nu_0(\pi - \phi_1 + \phi_2)) $$
> where $\Delta\beta_2 = \tilde{\beta}_2 - \beta_2$ and $\Delta\Phi = \Phi - \Phi_0$.

In the last equation of the above snippet, I cannot reproduce the first equality relationship. I obtain the following:

$$
\begin{aligned}
\Delta M_{12} &= \tilde{\beta}_2\sin\Phi - \beta_2\sin\Phi_0 \\
&= \tilde{\beta}_2\sin(\Phi_0+\Delta\Phi) - \beta_2\sin\Phi_0 \\
&= \tilde{\beta}_2\left[\sin\Phi_0\cos\Delta\Phi + \cos\Phi_0\sin\Delta\Phi\right] - \beta_2\sin\Phi_0 \\
&\approx \tilde{\beta}_2\left[\sin\Phi_0 + \cos\Phi_0\Delta\Phi\right] - \beta_2\sin\Phi_0 \\
&= \Delta\beta_2\sin\Phi_0 + \tilde{\beta}_2\cos\Phi_0\Delta\Phi
\end{aligned}
$$
where $\Delta\Phi \ll 1$ has been used for the approximation. So the difference of this result is that $\tilde{\beta}_2$ appears in the equation rather than $\beta_2$. This, however, prevents expressing the quantity $\Delta\beta_2$ in terms of the unperturbed betatron functions (since $\tilde{\beta}_2$ appears on the r.h.s. of the equation). What am I missing?